# Using a context processor in conjunction with Jinja template variables

Tags: python, unicode, flask, jinja2

I am in the midst of deploying Stripe and it requires that that payment values being passed into it are stated in "cents" rather than dollars. I can handle this on the backend (i.e I can process a payment for the appropriate amount) but in order to render properly in Stripe's UI, I must convert the price to cents. ($400 becomes 40000 cents)

I am attempting to use a context processor to convert the dollar price I store in my database to dollars which I can successfully do with the following code in my views.py file:

```
@buy_blueprint.context_processor
def utility_processor():
  def format_price(amount):
    return u'{0:.0f}'.format(amount)
  return dict(format_price=format_price)
```

and the following inserted in to my template.html file

```
Course Price: {{ format_price(40000) }}
```

Which renders as 40000 - perfect.

But what I want to do is something like:

```
{% for course in courses %}
<p> Course Name: {{ course.course_name }} Course Price: {{ course.price }} Max Number of Students: {{ course.max_number_students}}   Remaining Space: {{ course.spaces_left }}
{% if course.spaces_left > 0 %}
<form action="{{ url_for('buy.buy')}}" method="POST">
 <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
  data-key={{key}}
  data-amount= {{ format_price(course.price)}}
  data-name="Super teacher"
  data-label="Great  Dancing"
  data-description="Learn to Dance">
 </script>
 {% else %}
 <p>No more space</p>
 {% endif %}
<input type="hidden" name="course_id" value="{{course.id}}" />
</form>
```

But the issue is that:

```
data-amount= {{ format_price(course.price)}}
```

throws the following error:

```
 File "/Users/workhorse/flask-intro/project/buy/views.py", line 92, in format_price

    return u'{0:.0f}'.format(amount)

    ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'unicode'
```

I know this is unicode issue, just not sure how to go about fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the number first:

```
def format_price(amount):
    return u'{0:.0f}'.format(int(amount))
```

Or perhaps:

```
def format_price(amount):
    return u'{0:.0f}'.format(100*int(amount))
```

Comment: Attempted this    `code`def utility_processor():
    def format_price(amount):
        return u'{0:.0f}'.format(int(100*amount))
    return dict(format_price=format_price)    but the error came back   `code` TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'    return u'{0:.0f}'.format(int(100*amount))

Comment: There is an error in the second code sample in my answer. I will fix it.

Comment: @JoshKerbel - look at my recent change.

Comment: Much thanks -it was actually an uncaught None value that was tripping me up - Couldn't figure out where it was coming from